# How can I determine the MySqlException.Number?

Tags: mysql, exception

I am thinking of creating a case statement for the MySqlExceptions, based on the `Number` Property. Is there an easy way to determine if the exception relates to a specific case? For example, does the `Number` "1062" *always* refer to "Duplicate Entry"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to mysql documentation the answer to your question is, Yes.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html

or for 5.6

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/error-messages-server.html

when in doubt just go to dev.mysql...